# Acessing content of Instance variable in Post method

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

Below is a fragement of my code

```
 def LoadCategory(self, filter_string):
        time.sleep(1)
        self.heading = ""

        self.Question_title = list()
        self.Question_tag = list()
        self.Question_body = list()
        self.Question_who_ask = list()
        self.Question_who_email = list()
        self.Question_key = list()
        self.Question_Date = list()
# list is then populated



   def post(self):          
                self.response.write(self.Question_body)

# want to print out self.Question_body in post method.
```

But the list is empty. what is the right way to access the content of the variable ?

Comment: You are not showing enough code.  How/When is `LoadCategory` being called.

Comment: And you definitely need to show how the "list is then populated".

Comment: So did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution assuming you are inside a request class. Although using self to assign variables to the class is not a good approach as said before.

```
def LoadCategory(self, filter_string):
        time.sleep(1)
        self.heading = ""

        self.Question_title = list()
        self.Question_tag = list()
        self.Question_body = list()
        self.Question_who_ask = list()
        self.Question_who_email = list()
        self.Question_key = list()
        self.Question_Date = list()
# list is then populated



   def post(self):
                self.LoadCategory(filter_string)          
                self.response.write(self.Question_body)
```

Also it would be better if you name LoadCategory to load_category or loadcategory. Try following the [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) which states that the function names should be lowercase